# XRDP won't start under CentOS 7

Tags: centos, xrdp

I just install last version of CentOS 7 and I need to start XRDP.

I installed XRDP without error.

When I execute

```
# systemctl start xrdp.service
```

I am facing error

> Failed to start xrdp.service:Unit not found

What do I missing here?

Comment: Do you have SELinux activated?

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated SELinux by advice of Romeo Ninov and using this manual was able to install XRDP.

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

Notice: You have to reload computer after you change SELinux config file.